# How to deal with google apikey when using google map inside an iframe on another domain

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

I have a website page with google map and several markers on it. These markers represent specific data I own in my database. On click on a marker, details below the map appears with photos. 
Some local businesses are interested to have the same page on their own business website. I was thinking about offering this service within an iFrame so that the local business only have to add 3 lines of code to have the same full page.

Here I'm facing the problem of the quota limit usage of google map. I would like the business to provide it's own apikey in the iframe url so that I can use it when displaying the map. But the REFERER URL in the iframe will be my domain and not the one of the business domain. That will cause problem as and apikey is limited to a specific url.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the client id or name as a query parameter in the iframe and then check the client id or name using javascript and including the google map javascript dynamically based on the client. This will allow you to include a different key for each client. The client will have to provide you with their api keys and add your website in the list of domains allowed to use that key.

```
function includeGoogleMap()
{

// get client id or name from query parameter 
    var client = getParameterByName('clientid'); 

    if(client == "ABC"){
       document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=ABCKEY"></script>');
    }else if(client == "DEF"){
       document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=DEFKEY"></script>');
    }
    else if(client == "GHI"){
       document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=GHIKEY"></script>');
    }
}

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: I thought an apikey was linked to only 1 domain. It solves my problem then.. thank you Joyson!